# Message header and XML

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I have an xml file. I have to add the XMl file to message header of WCF request.

I am using OperationContextScope for this

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(myClient.InnerChannel))
        {
            var samlHeader = CreateSAMLAssertion();
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                    // Add smalheader which is a xml hear

                );       
        }
```

edit:

samlHeader  xml looks like this

```
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/x/xxxxx.xsd" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
 <Assertion ID="xxxxx" IssueInstant="xxxxxxx" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
 <--Removed-->
 </Assertion>
</Security>
```

I want the struct of the SOAP request to look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope ........>
    <soapenv:Header>
          I want to add my xml (smalheader) here
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

edit complete

Can any one please point me to the right direction

Comment: You want to add an XML **file** to the header of a WCF message (which is itself XML if you're using SOAP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your XML as an XElement (in my case it's a string you could use a file). Then using a BodyWriter class like below.  I was able to convert the XML into a Message and add them that way:

```
public class StringXmlDataWriter : BodyWriter
{
    private string data;

    public StringXmlDataWriter(string data)
        : base(false)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(data);
    }
}

public void ProcessHeaders()
    {
        string headers = "<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"> <wsa:MessageID>1337</wsa:MessageID> </soapenv:Header>";

        var headerXML = XElement.Parse(headers);

        foreach (var header in headerXML.Elements())
        {
            var message = Message.CreateMessage(OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageVersion, header.Name.LocalName, new StringXmlDataWriter(header.ToString()));
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.CopyHeadersFrom(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I made a class called SAMLAssertion. made the assertion elements properties of the class. Serialized the class and added in my header. OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(// seriallized class). I dont have the code for you as it was part of my previous job.Thanks